# How to calculate a darker hex color

Tags: javascript

Using [this solution](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lighten-darken-color/) I am trying to calculate the darker range of a color but the output is doesn't look like correct Hex value (missing one value).

```
> #84079
```

What am I doing wrong?

```js
function LightenDarkenColor(col, amt) {
  
    var usePound = false;
  
    if (col[0] == "#") {
        col = col.slice(1);
        usePound = true;
    }
 
    var num = parseInt(col,16);
 
    var r = (num >> 16) + amt;
 
    if (r > 255) r = 255;
    else if  (r < 0) r = 0;
 
    var b = ((num >> 8) & 0x00FF) + amt;
 
    if (b > 255) b = 255;
    else if  (b < 0) b = 0;
 
    var g = (num & 0x0000FF) + amt;
 
    if (g > 255) g = 255;
    else if (g < 0) g = 0;
 
    return (usePound?"#":"") + (g | (b << 8) | (r << 16)).toString(16);
  
}
var firstColor = LightenDarkenColor("#3068A1", -20); 
var NewColor = LightenDarkenColor(firstColor, -20); 

console.log(NewColor);
```

Comment: you might have to pad with a leading `0`

Comment: I don't think this question is poor quality, it's clear what they're asking and clear what their issue is. They need to pad their output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
(usePound?"#":"") + (g | (b << 8) | (r << 16)).toString(16);
```

to this

```
(usePound?"#":"") + ('00000'+(b | (g << 8) | (r << 16)).toString(16)).slice(-6);
```

This will make sure that there are 6 digits and it fixes the green and blue location which were off in the original article.

- `(r << 16)` moves the red to bits 32 to 47
- `(g << 8)` moves the green to bits 16 to 31
- and `b` leaves the blue in bits 0-15.

**UPDATE**

As was pointed out the `b` and `g` variables are reading the wrong values as well. So you want to do the following as well:

```
var g = ((num >> 8) & 0x00FF) + amt;

var b = (num & 0x0000FF) + amt;
```

Swap where the `b` and `g` get their values.

If you don't want to swap those then change my original line to this:

```
(usePound?"#":"") + ('00000'+(g | (b << 8) | (r << 16)).toString(16)).slice(-6);
```

Comment: I think Mona is trying to find a darker range of color. Swapping `g` and `b`, sets the `firstColor` to green instead of a darker blue, [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/ufk2ha0j/1/). Without swapping seems to give what Mona is looking for, [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/ufk2ha0j/2/).

Comment: It is RGB and the code in the article was making it RBG. I had figured that out about an hour before this questions was asked. That is why I switched the `g` and the `b` in the code.

Comment: You have to switch it everywhere in the function not just in the return statement.

Comment: Hi Intervalia and Anthony and thank you guys both for helping me on this. @Intevalia, with respect on what you have done I think Anthony is right because I am getting greenish color on darker blue! when using your solutin

Comment: Sorry, when I wrote my version of this code I had fixed the reading of `b` and `g`. So I needed to also fix the output line. I have updated the answer to match what you have been saying. **Thank you for pointing it out.**